# Use OpenCV Source Without Building Libraries

Tags: linux, opencv

Is it possible to use OpenCV source without building shared libraries in Linux ? If possible how can I add all OpenCV source file to my project ? And also If I build debug version of OpenCV then Is it possible to debug through each function in OpenCV ?

Comment: What is the motivation for this ?

Comment: I don't want to use library at run time. I need to create an application with full source without using any libraries.

Comment: OK, but why ? What perceived problem are you hoping to solve by doing this ?

Comment: Actually I am not facing any problems using those libraries. But I want know more about opencv source, I want to debug through openCV source and this is only for improving  my knowledge.

Comment: OK - but you don't need to include the source to debug it - just build debug versions of the libraries and you'll be able to step into the library functions in your debugger and view source etc.

Comment: Hi thanks for the information. But is it possible to create project using OpenCV source.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29412/discussion-between-haris-and-paul-r)